# How to assign array in a BPEL process

Tags: jdeveloper, bpel

I have a simple string as input and after calling a web service which adds the string to an array.Now i have to assign the array to the output(which i have set as a string array in the schema).The enterprise manager gives a fault and says the  result contains multiple nodes for the XPath expression given.The Assign activity is shown as pending.So basically how do i assign an array or a list to the output variable which is also set as an array.The wsdl file used is:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>

<definitions
     name="ReturnTypeService"
     targetNamespace="http://examples2/"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:tns="http://examples2/"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    >
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://examples2/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:7101/Examples2-Examples2-context-root/ReturnTypePort?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="display">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:display"/>
    </message>
    <message name="displayResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:displayResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="ReturnType">
        <operation name="display">
            <input message="tns:display"/>
            <output name="displayResponse"
            message="tns:displayResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="ReturnTypePortBinding" type="tns:ReturnType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="display">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="ReturnTypeService">
        <port name="ReturnTypePort" binding="tns:ReturnTypePortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:7101/Examples2-Examples2-context-root/ReturnTypePort"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

---

@vanto Is there a way to assign an array from input variable to invoke_input variable?The problem is there are multiple inputs in my web service so i am not able to copy the wrapping element in input variable to wrapping variable in invoke variable.Will copy the snippet of the code here :

```
<assign name="Assign1">
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:dsaName"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/dsaName"/>
            </copy>
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:linesOfData"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/linesOfData"/>
            </copy>
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:description"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/description"/>
            </copy>
            <copy>
                <from variable="inputVariable" part="payload"
                      query="/ns2:process/ns2:application"/>
                <to variable="Invoke1_processList_InputVariable"
                    part="parameters" query="/ns1:processList/application"/>
            </copy>
        </assign>
```

The problem is only one is of list type all others are of string type.The XML for this is:

```
<element name="process">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                     <element name="dsaName" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="linesOfData" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

                    <element name="description" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </sequence>
    </complexType>
        </element>
    <element name="processResponse">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="result" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the `<assign>` and the XSD contents.

Comment: <xs:element name="display" type="tns:display"/>

<xs:element name="displayResponse" type="tns:displayResponse"/>

<xs:complexType name="display">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="displayResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>

Comment: ^This is the xsd.The <assign> is:
 <assign name="Assign2">
            <copy>
                <from variable="Invoke1_display_OutputVariable"
                      part="parameters" query="/ns1:displayResponse/return"/>
                <to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
                    query="/ns2:processResponse/ns2:result"/>
            </copy>
        </assign>

Answer (score 1):

A from-spec and to-spec must not select more than one element or attribute. In your case it appears to select all `<return>` elements in your variable's part (i.e. the items of the array). Try to copy the element that wraps the items (i.e. the ns1:displayResponse element) and copy this element to ns2:processResponse (the wrapping element in the to-variable).

Since both source and target elements seem to be in different namespaces and are of different types, you probably need to run it through an XSLT script (using `doXSLTransform`) to translate it from the source schema to the target schema.

Comment: Great to hear that. Do you need any more help with this question?